# Frame object in tkinter not grouping widgets

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, widget

I have just started to use the `tkinter` module. I am trying to group different widgets together into an entirely new widget using one of my custom classes which inherits from the `Frame` object and want to stack 4 such new widgets vertically.

Each of the new widgets contain 1 `Label`, 3 `Entry` widgets, and 2 `Button` widgets (with the button widgets serving different purposes in each one of the 4 new widgets).

To arrange them vertically, I am using the `pack()` method with no parameters. The **problem** is that instead of getting displayed in a vertical manner with all the 6 old widgets placed inside the new widget in a 'grouped' fashion, I am getting a 'skewed' display with all the buttons 'mixed' with each other (all the widgets with pack value of `'left'` are displayed first while the widgets with pack value of `'right'` are displayed next).

Here is part of my class `OperationPanel` (the actual class is too large to display but the other operations like subtraction etc. exist and all the functions to which the buttons are linked to also exist):

```
class OperationPanel(Frame):
    def __init__(self, app, operation):
        Frame.__init__(self, app)
        if operation == "addition":
            Label(app, text="Addition:").pack()
            self.num1 = Entry(app)
            self.num1.pack(side = LEFT)
            self.num2 = Entry(app)
            self.num2.pack(side = LEFT)
            self.disp = Entry(app)
            self.disp.pack(side = LEFT)
            Button(app, text="Reset", command=self.reset_add).pack(side = RIGHT)
            Button(app, text="Add!",  command=self.calc_add).pack(side = RIGHT)

        elif operation == "subtraction":
            Label(app, text="Subtraction:").pack()
            self.num1 = Entry(app)
            self.num1.pack(side = LEFT)
            self.num2 = Entry(app)
            self.num2.pack(side = LEFT)
            self.disp = Entry(app)
            self.disp.pack(side = LEFT)
            Button(app, text="Reset", command=self.reset_sub).pack(side = RIGHT)
            Button(app, text="Subtract!", command=self.calc_sub).pack(side = RIGHT)

        elif operation == "multiplication":
            Label(app, text="Multiplication:").pack()
            self.num1 = Entry(app)
            self.num1.pack(side = LEFT)
            self.num2 = Entry(app)
            self.num2.pack(side = LEFT)
            self.disp = Entry(app)
            self.disp.pack(side = LEFT)
            Button(app, text="Reset", command=self.reset_mul).pack(side = RIGHT)
            Button(app, text="Multiply!",  command=self.calc_mul).pack(side = RIGHT)

        elif operation == "division":
            Label(app, text="Division:").pack()
            self.num1 = Entry(app)
            self.num1.pack(side = LEFT)
            self.num2 = Entry(app)
            self.num2.pack(side = LEFT)
            self.disp = Entry(app)
            self.disp.pack(side = LEFT)
            Button(app, text="Reset", command=self.reset_div).pack(side = RIGHT)
            Button(app, text="Divide!",  command=self.calc_div).pack(side = RIGHT)
...
```

And here are my calls to `pack` the `OperationPanel` objects:

```
OperationPanel(app, "addition").pack()
OperationPanel(app, "subtraction").pack()
OperationPanel(app, "multiplication").pack()
OperationPanel(app, "division").pack()
```

And here is how the GUI looks right now:

Part 1:

[image: the left side of the image]

Part 2:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're creating all of the widgets with a parent of `app`. They parent should be `self`:

```
if operation == "addition":
    Label(app, text="Addition:").pack()
    self.num1 = Entry(self)
    ...
```